# Forcing authenticated smtp e-mails with whitelist

Tags: exim

I need an exim setting which could allow only authenticated smtp emails, except when the e-mail comes from `root@servername`, for example. That's what I have today:

```
acl_not_smtp (custom_begin_outgoing_notsmtp_checkall)

deny
authenticated = *
condition = ${if !eq {root@$primary_hostname}{${address:$h_from:}}}
message = REJECTED
accept
```

This solution blocks all non-authenticatd emails. Anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to call another acl: acl_smtp_rcpt. Find out to what name this acl is mapped on your server. In Debian it is acl_check_rcpt.

To test for a sender, the sender must be already given, which is true when the remote end sends the "RCPT TO:" command. Without having tried, I would do something like the following in acl_check_rcpt:

```
accept authenticated = *
accept senders = root@servername
deny message = Rejected
```

You should not rely on a sender address which easily could be forged. You could test against the sending host with

```
    accept senders = root@servername
           hosts = 127.0.0.1 : localhost
```

additionally, to be sure the message's origin is your server.

Mostly local message do not get received by smtp. There the acl in your configuration comes in: acl_not_smtp. But again, search to what name this is mapped.

Comment: Hi Adrian, could you explain better how it works?

Comment: What part should be better explained? You may find your answer in the [exim documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html) online.